# checkstyle not checking space indentation in XML

Tags: java, xml, maven, checkstyle

I want checkstyle to check for the indentation in `xml`/`properties` (and if possible in `yml`) file as well.

However, with my current config, I am unable to get it done. Here is what my project structure look like

```
.
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── checkstyle.xml
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   └── test
```

and my `checkstyle.xml` file configuration for this specific problem is

```
<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <property name="severity" value="error"/>

    <property name="fileExtensions" value=""/>
    <property name="basedir" value="."/>
    <!-- Checks for whitespace                               -->
    <!-- See http://checkstyle.sf.net/config_whitespace.html -->
    <module name="FileTabCharacter">
        <property name="eachLine" value="true"/>
    </module>
```

I have set the `basedir` to `.` and tried with `/` as well (since my checkstyle is in `config/checkstyle` location). I have also tried it without the `basedir` property but it doesn't report a XML indentation issue when my XML is indented with 4 spaces. I am talking about `pom.xml`. How can i make sure that `checkstyle` checks the xml file.

P.S:

I am using checkstyle version 7.0 in my maven depdencies and executing check as `mvn checkstyl:checkstyle`

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>validate</id>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>${checkstyle.config.location}</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>

                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean *check for the indentation*? How should it behave? Should it force usage of tabs, or should it check that each tag is indented with four spaces?

Comment: Your current config will only check if there is a tab used anywhere and it will report it.

Comment: I want to check that it's idented with 2 spaces and not 4

Comment: It is not possible with checkstyle.

Answer (score 1):

Checkstyle doesn't have an indentation check for other files then java ones so it is not possible to use it for checking it in XML files.
Basically all `TreeWalker` checks are for java files (like `IndentationCheck`), all others can be used for other files (XML, properties, etc.) but there is a very limited number of those (e.g. `FileTabCharacterCheck`).

You will need to use other tool for that, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [xcop](https://github.com/yegor256/xcop).

`xcop filename.xml`
or `xcop name.xml --fix`

It will automatically fix your xml file.